# Odoo Reports - wkhtmltopdf error with default font

Tags: odoo, report, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-16

After a lot of search, I have found a problem with the default fonts in Odoo at the Reports.
The error is if I set a text in the report with  , normally the text between these two should get strong, but all the text on the whole page gets strong.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl4US.png)

```
    <t t-set="information_block" style="font-family:arial">

        <t t-if="doc.partner_shipping_id == doc.partner_invoice_id">
            Invoicing and Shipping Address:
        </t>
        <t t-else="">
           <strong>Invoicing Address:</strong>
        </t>

        <div t-field="doc.partner_invoice_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;phone&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True, &quot;phone_icons&quot;: True}"/>
        <t t-if="doc.partner_shipping_id != doc.partner_invoice_id">
            Shipping Address:
            <div t-field="doc.partner_shipping_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;phone&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True, &quot;phone_icons&quot;: True}"/>
        </t>
    </t>
```

Odoo is set to the default font Lato. The code is from my custom module, but it's a copy of the original report_saleorder_document.
The fault is also in the sales order report if I print it with wkhtmltopdf.

But if i set in code the font to arial:

```
<div style="font-family:arial;">  <strong>Invoicing Address:</strong> </div>
```

The pdf is correct:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcD2Y.png)

Does anyone have an idea where the fault is coming from and how to solve it correctly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with font conversion between HTML and PDF.

In this case you seem to have avoided the common failures of missing fonts due to limited permissions or wrong location and thus the font is correctly Lato. However note as regular it is already much stronger than many others and here we see where a division between "normal" and HTML `<strong>` changes the functionality on the left but not the style from regular to bold as shown on the right.

So the answer is there needs to be a style change from one font to another even if it's the same family.

[image]

There are several ways to try and divide a line into styles but `strong` and `b` on their own will not change the font from one to another. Here I added an inline style change via style class="b"

style

```
b  { font-family: 'Lato-Bold'; font-style: bold; font-weight: 800;}
```

body

```
generally be <b class="b">used in applications such as WkHtmltox</b>
```

Note the  PDF name is not the Lato-Bold.TTF name but the internal LatoBold name and has the correct effect.

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Lato-Bold'; font-style: bold; font-weight: bold; src: url("file:///C:/Users/lez/Downloads/Apps/Fonts/ttf/Lato-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"); }
```

[image]